# Deformation Retract of Open Square With 3 Points Removed

Tags: algebraic-topology, deformation-theory

Consider the open unit square with three points removed (say $a, b, c$) $S=(0,1)\times(0,1)-\left\{a, b, c\right\}$. Is a bouquet of three circles (wedge sum of three circles) a deformation retract of $S$? If so, why?

Comment: Yes, it is. You can also generalise to $n$ points deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick any of the points remaining in the square. Draw loops starting at that point, encircling a single one of the removed points, without self intersections, and without intersecting the other two loops.

Since the interior of the loops have a removed point each, then they can be retracted to the points of the loop. The exterior of the concatenation of all the loops can be retracted to the points of the loops as well.

Comment: Does this logic work for the closed square with three points removed as well?

Comment: @Nina Yes, except that you need to make a distinction. If some of the points removed belong to the boundary, then you can't loop around them. You would loop around the removed points in the interior only. Then the closed square with the points removed deforms to a a wedge of loops with one loop for each point removed **from the interior** of the square.

Comment: I see, so the total number of circles in our bouquet would directly correspond to the number of points in the interior specifically. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Nina That's right. That's probably why your original problem is a claim about the open square, such that there are no ambiguities or multiple cases in the solution.

Comment: Right, that makes sense, thanks again!

Comment: As I think about this again I don’t see why we would get a wedge of 3 circles for a closed square with 2 removed interior points, I can only see this becoming a wedge of 2 circles.

Comment: @Nina If you remove two interior points from a closed square, you will be able to retract to a wedge of two circles, yes. If you removed three points from the interior, then three circles. Now, if you remove two points from the interior, and one from the boundary, then you will be able to retract to a wedge of *two* circles again. The removed point from the boundary would not add a third circle to the count.

Comment: That makes sense now, thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

Take the square with one point removed. You can certainly radiallyretract to the boundary  to just get $S^1$.

For $2$ points removed, put one at $(1/3,1/2)$ and $(2/3,1/2)$ (which I'll include just for concreteness.

Using the vertical line at $x=1/2$, you can radially retract each "half of the square" onto the boundary of the "half square."

You can do this for $n$ points removed, by spacing them evenly and considering "$1/3$ squares" and so forth.

Comment: Why does this becomes a wedge of three circles? I can only see this becoming a wedge of two circles.

Comment: It does, that was two points removed. Do the same thing for three

Comment: So a closed square with two points removed doesn’t deformation rectract to a wedge of 3 circles?

Comment: No definitely not.

Comment: What about a torus with two points removed?

Comment: Different story. Can u do it for one point removed? There are many answers on this site discussing that

Comment: Yeah I understand that one, it’s with two points I don’t.

Comment: See #5 here https://www.google.com/amp/www.math3ma.com/mathema/2016/4/18/clever-homotopy-equivalences%3fformat=amp

Comment: I see now! Thank you :)